# Prove that a sequence converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-writing, uniform-convergence, cauchy-sequences

I am a little insecure about my proof because the book provide a longer one, can you check it? Thanks in advance

> Let $I\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be an interval and $f,f_n$ functions from I to $\mathbb{R}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $(f_n)$ uniformly converges to $f$.
>   Let $t_0 \in I$ such that for every $n$ exists $l_n=\lim_{t\to t_0}f_n(t)$.
>   Prove that $(l_n)$ converges.

Let $\epsilon >0$ and $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$; we have $|l_n-l_m|=|lim_{t \to t_0}(f_n(t)-f_m(t))|=lim_{t \to t_0}|f_n(t)-f_m(t)| \le lim_{t \to t_0}\epsilon=\epsilon$ if $n, m$ are sufficiently large because $(f_n)$ is uniformly convergent. So $(l_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence and therefore it converges.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I'm not sure of what you are saying, what if you take $f_n=f$ with f discontinuous in $t_0$? For example $f: [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}, x \to 1_{\{1\}}(x)$ and $t_0 = 1$

Comment: The proof is correct.

Comment: A mathematician would say "OK" but a marker on an exam for an elementary course might demand some more  detail.

Comment: @user. $l_n$ does not necessarily converge to $f(t_0)$.